# Inject an object in at runtime based on the value of another object using Autofac

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, autofac

How do you inject an object in at runtime based on the value of another object using Autofac?

I want to do something like below, where I can register each AggregateQuoteManager and invoke the one I need at runtime based on tenancy which I get from ITenancyContext

```
    builder.RegisterType<AggregateQuoteManagerTenancyA>().Named<IAggregateQuoteManager>("aggregateQuoteManagerForTenancyA");

    builder.RegisterType<AggregateQuoteManagerTenancyB>().Named<IAggregateQuoteManager>("aggregateQuoteManagerForTenancyB");

    builder.RegisterType<AggregateQuoteManagerDefault>().Named<IAggregateQuoteManager>("aggregateQuoteManagerDefault");

    builder.Register(c =>
            {
                var tenancy = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<ITenancyContext>().ShortCode;

                switch (tenancy.ShortCode)
                {
                    case "Tenancy-A":
                        return c.ResolveNamed<IAggregateQuoteManager>("aggregateQuoteManagerForTenancyA");
                    case "Tenancy-B":
                        return c.ResolveNamed<IAggregateQuoteManager>("aggregateQuoteManagerForTenancyB");
                    default:
                        return c.ResolveNamed<IAggregateQuoteManager>("aggregateQuoteManagerDefault");
                }
            }
     ).As<IAggregateQuoteManager>();
```

Comment: So, what's the problem? Your code sample does work, or doesn't it?

Comment: Also, unrelated to the question: Don't use DependencyResolver.Current.GetService in your lambda if Autofac is already your dependency resolver. Resolve everything from the inbound component context.

Comment: The "other object" looks like a tenant identifier. Have you tried the Autofac multitenant support? http://autofac.readthedocs.org/en/latest/advanced/multitenant.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took Travis Illig's approach- "The "other object" looks like a tenant identifier. Have you tried the Autofac multitenant support?" - its much simpler, thank you